# jQuery .serialize() not a function

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

Why does this not work?

```
var me = $('#'+id);
var content = $(me).find('input').val().serialize();
```

I get `TypeError: $(me).find("input").val().serialize is not a function`

Comment: Why you are trying to serialize a string value ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `$(me).find('input').val()` is a string and not a jQuery object, it doesn't have the [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) function.

If you want to serialize the input (with its value), use `$(me).find('input').serialize();`

But be sure to really need it : this function is rarely useful for just one input (we generally use it for forms). If you just want the value, use `$(me).find('input').val()` and if you're debugging and want to inspect the element, use `console.log($(me))` and open the console of your browser.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `.serialize()` on form directly.
you can serialize form as below

```
var serializeData = $('form').serialize();
```

Comment: @dystroy Thanks  I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to serialize form selected by `querySelector` that gave me error but after selecting the form via jQuery `let form = $('form');` fixed this